# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on same subnet

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-2008, udp, port

PC1 - Windows 7 SP1 64 bit and PC2 - Windows 8 Pro 32 bit

I am able to PortQry port 1434 UDP from PC1 to know that the server is available in PC2.

However with the below code I get an Error. What am I missing?

**Code:**
    string connectionString = string.Format("User Id=user1;" + 
                                           "password=pwd_value;" +
                                           "Data Source={0};", sqlServerInstance);
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

**Error:** A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 1):

Start with this list:

- Make sure that SQL Browser service is running on the PC where the SQL
  Server is installed.
- Enable remote connections to
  the SQL Server (with SQL Server Configuration Manager utility -> SQL Server
  Network Configuration). By default SQL Server denies remote connections.
- Make sure you're added appropriate rules to
  Windows Firewall to enable connections to SQL Browser and SQL Server.

Comment: Is enabling remote connections same as enabling TCP/IP port 1433?  I added the port 1433 to all the TCP/IP (IP Addresses) and then restarted the SQL Server service and then it worked. Need I add 1433 to all the IP Adresses?

Comment: To enable remote connections to an SQL Server instance, just open SQL Server Configuration Manager, then expand SQL Server Network Configuration node, select Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (or other instance you want to enable), then in the right pane you'll see Shared Menory (which is only used for local connections), Named Pipes, and TCP/IP (both are used for remote connections), and VIA (which I never used). I always enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP. I just doubleclick and set Enabled to Yes, then restart SQL Server. Some clients prefer to connect with Named Pipes, others with TCP/IP.

Comment: TCP/IP was already enabled. I had to explicitly add the port 1433 and restart it for the the remote connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the SQL 2008 Native Client? That maybe your issue.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Comment: Where should SQL 2008 Native Client be installed - PC1 or PC2?

Comment: It should be installed on all the clients directly accessing the sql server.  The sql server install should have already installed the native client on the machine hosting the sql server.  So if PC2 has the sql server on it PC1 should get the native client driver install.